# Determine if the triangle is right-angled using vectors.

Tags: inner-products

> Use vectors to decide whether the triangle with vertices
>   $P\langle 1, -3, -2\rangle, Q\langle2, 0, -4\rangle$, and $R\langle6, -2, -5\rangle$ is right-angled.

I tried taking the dot product $P\cdot Q$, $Q \cdot R$, and $P \cdot R$ but none are zero. However the triangle is right-angled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: You want to consider whether two sides are orthogonal; the directions of the sides are

$$P - Q, P - R, Q - R$$

respectively.

Comment: @user710587: I don't have to. Is this a new site rule? I certainly offered my thoughts. :)

Comment: I changed $<1,-3,2>$ to $\langle1,-3,2\rangle$.  That is standard.

Comment: You can't take the dot product of points, only vectors. It's unclear what your definition of dot product is and what vectors you're multiplying.

Comment: @user710587 It's implied that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is being viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user710587: Points can be represented by vectors.........

Comment: I agree, from my view though, it seemed that user Don was taking the dot product of the vertices of the right triangle, and by showing his work he might've stumbled across his mistake, though all which was received from my comment was lip service. :( It is also a bit disappointing that after all the efforts to answer and vote on this silly problem, user Don has failed to recognize either of the answers and instead is being petty on the comment-line.

Comment: A new site rule? See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), questions on meta, more help, etc..

Comment: @user710587: Sorry you didn't get what you want. Take your antics elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction vectors for the three sides are given by the *differences* in the vertices, not the vertices themselves. So consider the vectors

$$P - Q, P - R, Q - R$$ and see whether any of these are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

The three sides of the triangle correspond to vectors $P-Q$, $Q-R$, $R-P$.  Take dot products of those.